# What browser for S40 feature phones allow me to use interactive web apps?

Tags: web-browser, mobile, phone, series40

I have a Nokia 301, which runs on S40. I want to use Uber or Lyft on it. However, the browsers I can find are all pre-rendered server side, so interactive javascript stuff doesn't work. I've tried Opera Mini and UC Browser, but they're all server side rendering. The mobile sites for uber/lyft just show the broken stuff you see if you have javascript off.

Are there any compatible browsers that run websites normally? I can't find any.